# Parameters Grid Search for Keras LSTM on Time Series

Tags: time-series, lstm, tensorflow, keras

How do you do grid search for Keras LSTM on time series? I have seen various possible solutions, some recommend to do it manually with for loops, some say to use scikit-learn GridSearchCV. Feedback would be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

See here. Brownlee has a lot of good tutorials on time series: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-grid-search-deep-learning-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: It would improve the value of the answer, if you summarized the key points in your reference and added your point of view. A link could just be added as a comment.